# How execute `schema.sql` during spring boot test without embedded datasource configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, embedded-database, spring-boot-test

There is spring boot application with h2 database which is used as primary database. Also there is a `resource/schema.sql` which is loaded at startup by spring boot.

But during integration tests with `@SpringBootTest` spring boot does **not** load this `schema.sql`. Instead it requires to setup embedded database while there is `h2` db already.

Is there a way to execute `schema.sql` without embedded datasource configuration? And do it only once for all tests (e.g. using `@Sql` for schema creation for all test is not a solution)?

Comment: That is explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) in the reference guide. Hint look for the `spring.datasource.initialize` property.

Comment: `spring.datasource.initialize` do not work in tests. :(

Comment: If it isn't working you aren't using Spring Boot in your tests properly...

Comment: did you ever figure out how to only run it once for all tests?

Answer (score 7):

Annotate your class or method with `@Sql(scripts = "classpath:schema.sql", executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD)` where your schema.sql is on resources folder.

You need this if your tests are marked as integration tests. Spring boot will do this for you if you are running a unit test or just compiling with unit tests enabled which is the default.

Answer (score 3):

Set this in your properties file and then rename schema.sql to schema-test.sql
`spring.datasource.platform=test`

Spring boot automatically configures the embedded database for you as long as you have the it in the classpath (h2, hsqldb or derby)