# Spring boot: populate h2 db from schema in test/resources

Tags: spring-boot, h2

On my local machine I load an in-memory h2 database to start my spring boot application in a safe environment, here's the properties:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:mem:DB_TEST;Mode=Oracle
spring.datasource.platform: h2
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error: false
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Then, in my src/main/resources I have the file schema-h2.sql containing my local db initiations.

That's fine, but then I also have some junit tests I want to execute:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTest {

@Autowired
private MyController controller;

@Test
public void myTest(){
     controller.doSomething();
}
```

This is also fine, as the schema-h2.sql is seen.

Anyway according to me it would be better to put the schema-h2.sql in src/test/resources as it has to be used only on my local environment. Doing so also allows maven to exclude it from the final build and that is also pretty fine.

Anyway if I put it there the test keeps working...but the main application breaks as the schema-h2.sql is not found!

How to modify the above properties to specify that the shema-h2.sql has to be searched inside of the test/resources folder?

Thanks

Comment: If you use different application profiles, you can use default profile with `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always`  to load your schema on test phase, but when running your application you can use `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never` with another profile like `dev` or whatever. This way you enable shcema.sql feature for an specific profile but not the other

Comment: Profile is the same both for dev and test...I also don't want to clone the h2-schema.sql across the project :(

Comment: try using what is suggested in this chain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626269/how-execute-schema-sql-during-spring-boot-test-without-embeded-datasource-conf

Comment: Have you tried looking at `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` in your test class?

Answer (score 1):

For normal mode, the properties file is put in src/main/resources, 
and for the testing method, the properties file in the src/test/resources folder.

By Trying to run a test-class, eclipse runs EACH file ending with .sql (and thus containing a script to create tables or to insert data) it finds under src/main/resources and src/test/resources.
So if you put a script-file schema.sql (containing a script that creates a table: create table ..) in both folders, you'll get an "table already exits" error, if you let jut one, the test will run smoothly.
If you put a script-file (that insert data in a table) in both folder, both scripts will be run.

You can also use the `@PropertySource("..")` in your repository to tell spring where to find the properties-file to use.